# how do I get the url field on firefox for mac?

Tags: mac, firefox

I'm new to mac, I'm surprised not to see how to have the url toolbar shown permanently on firefox so how to get it ?

Comment: your Address Bar is missing? Quite odd. Care to show us a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are set to full screen which would hide the address bar.

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: +1 for the Shift + Command + F option, didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the `View` option on the Menu and select `Toolbars` and make sure `Navigation Toolbar` is ticked.